# How To Make Bot Wait For 2 Reactions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

I Want My Discord.py Bot To Wait For 2 Reactions...

The Code:

```
def check(reaction, user):
return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '1️⃣'
def check(reaction, user):
return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '2️⃣'

mm = await message.send(embed=embed1)
    await mm.add_reaction("1️⃣")
    await mm.add_reaction("2️⃣")
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",check=check,timeout=180)
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",check=check,timeout=180)
    if reaction:
        await mm.edit(embed=embed1)
    elif reaction:
        await mm.edit(embed=embed3)
```

Comment: Could you also include your `check` function?

Comment: ok ill add the check function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `check` function, you can check if the user's reaction is one in a given list, or you can use an `or statement`. In this example, I will use the former. Then, you can check which reaction it is, and continue from there. Do view the revised code below.

```py
def check(reaction, user):
    # Check if user is the author of the message
    # AND if the reaction emoji is in a list of set reactions, 1️⃣ and 2️⃣
    return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ["1️⃣","2️⃣"]

await mm.add_reaction("1️⃣")
await mm.add_reaction("2️⃣")
reaction, user = await bot.wait_for("reaction_add",check=check,timeout=180)
if str(reaction.emoji) == "1️⃣":
    # do something
elif str(reaction.emoji) == "2️⃣":
    # do something else
```